# How to disable auto calculation in libre office calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I want to fill a cell rang with values from a macro.
Since there are formulas depending on the inserted values the macro runs very long. Is there a way to dis-/enable table recalculation programatically ?. I want to disable table recalculation before filling the cell range and enable it after filling is done.

Answer (score 3):

`ThisComponent.EnableAutomaticCalculation(False) 
. . .
ThisComponent.CalculateAll
ThisComponent.EnableAutomaticCalculation(True)`

I'm assuming that the call to "CalculateAll" is not required as re-enabling automatic calculation with dirty cells will force a recalculation, but I'm paranoid :-)

Comment: I got all excited when I saw the title of your question as I was hoping it would answer mine as well. So I had to go and figure it out myself. Could you vote it as answer please?